# How do I make my player collide with my platform for all sides

Tags: python, pygame

So I been wondering how to make it so when my  player touches any side of my platform, the player will act like there is a wall there, for example,

https://gyazo.com/272b729154b0790fd3e004c761cdb658

Its just fazing though the sides and is only colliding with the top. I want it to stop doing that and actually collide with the sides and also the bottom to, I have tried to watch some tutorials but most of them were neither talking about a different topic or I just did not get it and also I have tried the code shown bellow but that's not working.

The code I have tried

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
             x_change = -7
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
             x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
             x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class bullet(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 10
        self.color = color
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox

white = (255,255,255)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(255,255,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(200,470,100,30,white)
platform2 = Platform(400,410,100,30,white)



# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2]




# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

# Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()


x = 10
y = 10

x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y

        


fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
             x_change = -7
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
             x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
             x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x

            
    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]and playerman.x > playerman.speed:
            playerman.x -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_d]and playerman.x < 700 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        playerman.x += playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_w]and playerman.y > playerman.speed:
        playerman.y -= playerman.speed

    if keys[pygame.K_s]and playerman.y <500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        playerman.y += playerman.speed

  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
        
           
                    
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    

                

    
    
        




    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual position of the stated in the floating point attributes `x` and `y`instead of the attribute `rect`. Add a method `get_rect()` to the class player, which updates the attribute `rect`. You'll need it for the collision test.

```py
class Player:
    # [...]

     def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())
```

Copy the position of the player into local variables (`px`, `py`) and change these variables instead of the position of the player when it is moved:

```
# lets player move
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y
if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
        px -= playerman.speed
if keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 700 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
    px += playerman.speed
if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
    py -= playerman.speed
if keys[pygame.K_s] and py <500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
    py += playerman.speed
```

Get a list of all platform rectangles and a rectangle with the new position of the player:

```py
platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
player_rect.topleft = (px, py)
```

Use [`collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) to test if it collides with any platform, if the player is not falling.
If the player doesn't collide with any platform then update the `x` coordinate of the player. This prevents the player from "running" in a platform:

```py
playerman.y = py
if not playerman.isJump and player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
    playerman.x = px
```

Use `get_rect()` for the collision test. If the player is on top of a platform, then the correct position is `playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height` rather than `playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1`:

```py
# About isJump
if not playerman.isJump:
    playerman.y += playerman.fall
    playerman.fall += 1
    playerman.isJump = False

    # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
    collide = False
    for Platform in platforms:
        if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect): # <--- get_rect()
            collide = True
            playerman.isJump = False
            
            # playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height + 1   <--- DELETE
            playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
            
            if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
            if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
```

---

Complete example

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")

# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())

class bullet(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 10
        self.color = color
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(255,255,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(200,470,100,30,white)
platform2 = Platform(400,410,100,30,white)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2]

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = -7
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 7

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 0

            x += x_change
            if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
                x = old_x
           
    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
            px -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 700 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        px += playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
        py -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and py <500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        py += playerman.speed

    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if not playerman.isJump and player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is not working for me, I copied the complete example because when I did the other things you told me to do it did not work so I just coped the full example but  that dose not work I'm trying to make it so if the player collides with the side's it will stop and not go through the sides.

Comment: @Windowman Sorry I've posted the wrong example. I've reposted your original code rather than the example with the changes. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To make a collision with sides use something like this:

```
x = (#whatever)
y = (#whatever)

x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
         x_change = -7
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
         x_change = 7

if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
         x_change = 0

x += x_change
if x > display_width - player_width or x < 0:
        x = old_x
```

A few variables such as display_width and player_width, x and y will need setting up.

Comment: Look at the update, the code you gave me dose not work.